# Printing to a printer that is not defined on the machine

Tags: printing

I am looking for a solution to programatically print a file to a printer that is not defined locally.  What I would like to do is send the file to printer perhaps by specifying the printer address (\MyPrintServer\PrinterName) and give it a print driver.  Does anyone know if this is possible and if there are any open source or relatively cheap options available?

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to print on a network printer that is not connected to your pc? I guess you have to connect it first before printing anything. If you want to connect it using code, then this might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff686807(v=VS.85).aspx .

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, I assume that you have a server and you want to print from a client computer. Also, if for any reason you don't have a driver install on the server, you would programmatically install the driver from the client-side. If so, I could possible be of help to you.

Also, check the link from Bogdan0x400.